# Why is the modal window not appearing in Selenium and Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, selenium

I am using Selenium and Python. On click of an image element as found here:

```
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'(//td[span[normalize-space(text())="Ram Lal"]])[1]/following-sibling::td[./input[@type="image"]]')))
```

this is the stuff that the button does to bring back a page, which does not happen in Selenium:

```
<input type="image" src="/rhis/images/add2.png" onclick="A4J.AJAX.Submit('modalFormResultPatientSearchPatientSearchForm',event,{'oncomplete':function(request,event,data){Richfaces.hideModalPanel('modalFormResultPatientSearch');},'similarityGroupingId':'modalFormResultPatientSearchPatientSearchForm:patientSearchDataTableId:0:patientContorlsubmitSearch','parameters':{'backingBeanName':'','patientId':'903242','patSearchMrno':'UH0000004013','onPatientSelectCallBack':'','modalFormResultPatientSearchPatientSearchForm:patientSearchDataTableId:0:patientContorlsubmitSearch':'modalFormResultPatientSearchPatientSearchForm:patientSearchDataTableId:0:patientContorlsubmitSearch'} ,'eventsQueue':'modalFormResultPatientSearchsearcha4jQueue'} );return false;" name="modalFormResultPatientSearchPatientSearchForm:patientSearchDataTableId:0:patientContorlsubmitSearch" id="modalFormResultPatientSearchPatientSearchForm:patientSearchDataTableId:0:patientContorlsubmitSearch">
```

I tried this trick in vain assuming it is a modal window problem:

```
driver.execute_script('var el=arguments[0]; setTimeout(function() { el.click(); }, 100);', element)
```

What could be the reason for the new modal window not appearing ?

Comment: Please share the link for inspect the web page.

Comment: Sorry @Vkt0r the application is not available on an external IP.

Comment: Have you tried to perform `submit()` action on the element, not `click()`?

Comment: Thanks @ZeinabAbbasi but i just abandoned that test case. The next time i meet such a case, will try submit().